# Cosmos Db CORS setting doesn't respect * in the allowed origins

Tags: azure, cors, azure-cosmosdb

I put * in Cosmos Db CORS setting, but when I try to access via browser, I get the following error:

[image]

Adding the localhost:3000 fixed the problem, but my expectation was adding all origins with *. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Even localhost:3000 shows that error message. This is the configuration screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you set just * or a list,*? Can you share screenshot of the portal setting?

Comment: Just a simple *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see here, it should be possible with a simple configuration as mentioned **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-cross-origin-resource-sharing#enable-cors-support-from-resource-manager-template)**,

```
 "allowedOrigins": "*"
```